# Is there a JQuery plugin that does wizard-forms, like this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

http://lal.com/minnesota

If you click on "flirt", then you click on "boy" and then click on "brunette"

It's like a javascript wizard form kind of thing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That shouldn't really be difficult to do.
You would have steps and each step can save a variable.

```
<div id="step1">Flirt</div>
<div id="step2">About a boy</div>
<div id="step3">Step 3...</div>
<div id="step4">Step 4...</div>
```

Then in your jquery script, you would hook onto the clicks of different elements inside of those steps and given that the inputs are clicked, hide and show new steps.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("step1").click(function(){
       //do some checking
    });
  });

    function showStep(step)
    {
       $("#" + step).show();
    }
    function hideAllSteps()
    {
      $("#step1").hide();
      $("#step2").hide();
    }
</script>
```

this is just a quick brute force demonstration and it should give you an idea of a quick and easy way to implement a wizard type look and feel using jquery. It's ugly, but it shows a concept.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [jswiz](https://github.com/shevchuk/jswiz) library. It lets you build wizards with jQuery too. 
Check docs and demo inside